# Restore Purchases issue Flutter - iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, revenuecat

I'm using RevenueCat for in-app purchases.

I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter app's in-app purchase (IAP) functionality, particularly with restoring purchases on iOS.

My app offers a non-consumable premium version that provides lifetime access to certain features. However, during the App Store review process, I received a rejection due to the following reason:

> Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase
>
> "We found that your app includes a feature to restore previously purchased in-app purchase products by entering the user's Apple ID and password. However, in-app purchases cannot be restored in this manner."

While the restoration process works smoothly on Android without any sign-in prompts, on iOS, it triggers a sign-in prompt, leading to the rejection.

it only happened for app store, everything was fine for google play

Here's the relevant code snippet from my app:

```
static Future<void> restorePurchases(
    PersistenceViewModel persistenceViewModel, BuildContext context) async {
  try {
    CustomerInfo customerInfo = await Purchases.restorePurchases();

    // Handle restored purchases
    if (customerInfo.allPurchasedProductIdentifiers.contains(premium)) {
      // Handle the restored product identifiers
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Premium version restored');
      }

      // Here I make the user premium if successfully restored
      await persistenceViewModel.setPremium(true);

      // Show Alert
      if (!context.mounted) return;

      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return const ShowRestoredAlert();
        },
      );
    }
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Error restoring purchases: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to resolve this issue and ensure that the restoration process works seamlessly on both iOS and Android. How can I modify my code to achieve this without triggering the sign-in prompt on iOS?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

I'd like to resolve this issue and ensure that the restoration process works seamlessly on both iOS and Android. How can I modify my code to achieve this without triggering the sign-in prompt on iOS?

Comment: what version of  purchases_flutter are you using? I do exactly the same you do in your code and it was never a problem for the review team.